# PHP Fatal error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt

Tags: centos, wordpress, selinux

I installed wordpress to CentOS from EPEL:

```
yum install wordpress
```

And it can only work if I manually disable SELinux. Otherwise I see this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should
>   *never* happen! in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 105, referer: http://www.myblog.com/wp-admin/

```
ls -Z /usr/share/zoneinfo
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 Africa
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 America
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 Antarctica
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 Arctic
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 Asia
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 Atlantic
...
(many lines skipped)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Once again your files have the wrong SELinux security contexts. [This is the same problem you had before.](https://serverfault.com/q/477635/126632)

At this point I suggest you relabel, not only the immediately affected files, but the entire filesystem.

```
restorecon -r -v /
```

Comment: After I relabel them, context always is set to user_home_t even if I change it to anything else....

Comment: Go find out who's messing with your system.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `restorecon`, you might need to get SELinux context survive a file system relabel, using the `semanage` command -

eg.

```
 semanage fcontext -a -t locale_t /usr/share/zoneinfo
 semanage fcontext -a -t locale_t /usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa
```

Read the RedHat documentation for [making persistent changes using semanage.](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html)